# How to round up millis() when divided into minutes?

Tags: arduino-uno

```
unsigned long milliseconds=millis();
// if at time of reading the above milliseconds = 599999 ie 1 millisecond short of 600000 ie 10 minutes
unsigned long minutes = (milliseconds/1000)/60;
// this will return 9 instead of 10.
```

How do you round the result to 10 minutes? I don't mean adding 1 to final result. It has to be within the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

To round to the nearest X in fixed point arithmetic: add 1/2 X (in the base units, msec, in this case) and divide by X (again, in the base units) so:
`milliseconds = (milliseconds + (30*1000L))/(60*1000L);`

The addition of 1/2 X causes a carry of one whole X if the fractional X in the original quantity was 1/2 X or greater. (Likewise, if the fractional X was less than 1/2 X, no carry will result).

Integer division naturally truncates any fractional amounts, so you'll be left with the rounded integer result.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple trick how to switch from integer math to floating point math and use round function.

```cpp
  unsigned long milliseconds = 599999;

  unsigned long minutes_long = (milliseconds/1000)/60;
  // minutes_long = 9

  double minutes_double = (milliseconds/1000.0)/60.0;
  // minutes_double = 9.99998...

  double minutes_rounded = round(minutes_double);
  // minutes_rounded = 10
```

There also exists a trick that allows calculation of `round` using integer math. It's perfect if you don't have enough memory for a cast.

```cpp
  unsigned long milliseconds;

  milliseconds = 600000 - 30*1000 - 1;
  //milliseconds = 569999

  unsigned long minutes_9 = (milliseconds+30000)/60000;
  // minutes_9 = 9

  milliseconds = 600000 - 30*1000;
  //milliseconds = 570000

  unsigned long minutes_10 = (milliseconds+30000)/60000;
  // minutes_10 = 10
```

Comment: try `double minutes_double = (milliseconds/1000.0)/60.0;`